# Flip edge of two triangles

Tags: algorithm, geometry, flip, vertices

I have an array with indices. Three of these indices make up a triangle. Now I take one triangle and search for another one with a shared edge. These triangles make up a diagonally split quadrangle now. How (in code) can I flip this diagonal edge/ the triangles so it connects the opposite diagonal? What I'm looking for is often called "flip edge" in 3D programs like Blender, Maya, 3ds max etc.

[image: quadrangle edge flip]

I'm stuck with this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on how you have implemented your structures. For example, if you have such a structure:

```
struct Vertex
{
    double position[3];
};

struct Triangle
{
    unsigned int vertices[3];
};

Vertex nodes[N_NODES];
Triangle triangles[N_TRIANGLES];
```

in which, `vertices` is an index to `nodes`, then given two triangles:

```
Triangle t1, t2;
```

If you have

```
t1.vertices[i1] = t2.vertices[j1];
t1.vertices[i2] = t2.vertices[j2];
```

which means `t1.vertices[i1] --- t1.vertices[i2]` is the shared edge with `t2.vertices[j1] --- t1.vertices[j2]`, and assuming `i3` and `j3` are the 3rd verices of `t1` and `t2` respectively, as indicated in this image:

[image]

Then you can do the flip just with changing some indices. The most straightforward way would be:

```
unsigned int t1_v[3], t2_v[3];

t1_v[0] = t1.vertices[i1];  // shared
t1_v[1] = t1.vertices[i2];  // shared
t1_v[2] = t1.vertices[i3];  // not shared

t2_v[0] = t2.vertices[j1];  // shared (unnecessary)
t2_v[1] = t2.vertices[j2];  // shared (unnecessary)
t2_v[2] = t2.vertices[j3];  // not shared

t1.vertices[0] = t1_v[0];  // previously shared
t1.vertices[1] = t1_v[2];  // previously not shared
t1.vertices[2] = t2_v[2];  // previously not shared

t2.vertices[0] = t2_v[0];  // previously shared
t2.vertices[1] = t2_v[2];  // previously not shared
t2.vertices[2] = t1_v[2];  // previously not shared
```

Note that, each new triangle consists of 2 unshared vertices and one of the shared ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your vertices in one array, I assume you recognize different rows by some fixed row length and make the triangles based on some pattern. I would suggest just to change this pattern how you assign three vertices together. You have to take care of not paired triangles if there are any